# Is $\sqrt{2/(27\pi n)}\sim n^{-1/2}$?

Tags: asymptotics

Is $\sqrt{2/(27\pi n)}\sim n^{-1/2}$?

Since
$$
\sqrt{\frac{2}{27\pi n}}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{27\pi}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=n^{-1/2},
$$
I would say, yes, of course.

Comment: $\sim$ usually denotes asymptotic equality, that is $a_n \sim b_b$ means $\frac{a_n}{b_n}\to 1$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on how you define the relation $\sim$. It is certainly the case that $\sqrt{2/(27\pi n)} = \Theta(n^{-1/2})$.

But if you define $f\sim g$ to mean that $f(n)/g(n)\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$, which is how $\sim$ is usually defined, then it is not true as the limit of the quotient of $\sqrt{2/(27\pi n)}$ and $n^{-1/2}$ in your case above is not $1$.

See [Asymptotic Notation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AsymptoticNotation.html).

Comment: With $\sqrt{2/(27\pi n)}=\Theta(n^{-1/2})$ you mean that $\sqrt{2/(27\pi n)}$ is of smaller or of the same order as $n^{-1/2}$ (big O-notation)?

Comment: Yes. More precisely, by $f=\Theta(g)$ I mean that for all $n\ge n_0$  for some $n_0$ I can sandwich $f(n)$ between $C_1 g(n)$ and $C_2 g(n)$ for two absolute positive constants $C_1$ and $C_2$. Formally this means that there exists an $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that there exist $C_1,C_2>0$ such that for all $n\ge n_0$ we have $C_1g(n)\le f(n)\le C_2g(n)$. It is also equivalent to saying that $f=O(g)$ and $f=\Omega(g)$.

Comment: If I have $f(n)\in\mathcal{O}(n^{-1/2})$ as $n\to\infty$ and $g(n)\in o(n^{-1/2})$ as $n\to\infty$, and then consider $f(n)-g(n)$ can I then neglect $g(n)$ as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: Asymptotically you will have $f-g \in O(n^{-1/2})$. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I have $h(n)=f(n)-g(n)$ and I know that $f(n)\sim\sqrt{2/(27\pi n)}$ and $g(n)\in o(n^{-1/2})$. I do not see why from this it follows that $h(n)\sim\sqrt{2/(27\pi n)}$.

Comment: Write it out: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{h(n)}{\sqrt{2/(27\pi n)}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)-g(n)}{\sqrt{2/(27\pi n)}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{f(n)}{\sqrt{2/(27\pi n)}}-\frac{g(n)}{\sqrt{2/(27\pi n)}})=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{\sqrt{2/(27\pi n)}}-0=1-0=1$, thus $h\sim\sqrt{2/(27\pi n)}$. (The limits are $1$ and $0$ because $f\sim \sqrt{2/(27\pi n)}$ and $f=o(n^{-1/2})$.

Comment: Ah, ok. The only thing thats now unclear to me is, why $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{g(n)}{\sqrt{2/(27\pi n)}}=0$.

Comment: Because $\sqrt{2/(27\pi n)}=\Theta(n^{-1/2})$ and $g=o(n^{-1/2})$.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understood. You helped me a lot, thanks.